# Temporarily reboot into Windows while suspending Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, suspend, hibernate

Is it possible reboot into Windows while **suspending** (or hibernating) Ubuntu, as opposed to choosing *Shut Down*, followed by *Restart*, if I have dual boot?

More precisely, I would like to be able to simply click a menu item next to where you have *Log Out...*, *Suspend* and *Shut Down...*, or use a shortcut, to reboot the machine while the current state of my running Ubuntu session is suspended and can be quickly brought back whenever I shut down Windows.

Ideally the boot loader should be customized so that when I choose to reboot into Windows, I am automatically booting Windows (for that single boot). Perhaps Grub supports this kind of temporary boot options. I don't know.

**The reason** I want to be able to quickly jump into Windows (and soon back to Ubuntu again) is because I have Windows programs that I frequently use which can only run under Windows, and running them under Wine or similar is not feasible (e.g., Adobe Lightroom). Annoyingly I am forced to still rely on Windows. Also, I am not the sole user of the computer, so jumping between OS is important to do swiftly. *The question is not about finding solutions to whether I can use a VM or similar to emulate my needs of Windows.*

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. Boot loaders don't work that way.

I am not a big fan of dual booting.  I think it's too much trouble to configure.  When I need both operating systems on a single machine, I choose the one I use the most as the main OS and run the secondary OS in as a virtual machine. This allows you to have both operating systems running on the same machine at the same time.
In the beginning, I had a Windows machine with Ubuntu running as a VM because I used Windows more often. Now I have an Ubuntu machine with a Windows VM.
I don't remember the last time I ran the Windows VM.

Comment: Well, this is precisely my problem: I use Ubuntu for everything but Windows for adobe Lightroom, which cannot run well under virtual machines. I'd like to think of my Windows installation as a "Lightroom installation" that I fire up every now and then. The idea is to fire it up without disrupting my Ubuntu session by shutting it down.

Comment: Which virtual machine did you try and what problem did you have ?

Comment: My machine does not have much memory and working with Lightroom 4.2 (having thousands of photos in the catalog and processing RAW files) requires every inch of power my machine got. Running Lightroom 4 under Linux is a notoriously tricky problem (please google). In any case, whether I can run Lightroom or not on a VM is outside the scope of my question. My question was simply about hibernating Ubuntu to reboot into Windows, not a discussion about what can or cannot be run in a VM. Being able to jump between OS also has other advantages, such as I am not the only user of the computer.

Comment: I think you're out of luck then. Boot loaders don't work that way.